# Redux form renders in unitialized state (and unable to be initialized) when reactively changing content on page

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I ran in to a problem the last few days that I just can't seem to crack.

**What I'm trying to do:** We have a sidebar, from which you can select a "**Study**". This study determines what you see on the main content block, as each **study** has different data and users assosciated with it. In the main content block, I have **forms** set up, one for each user.

**The problem:** On first page load, everything works fine. However, if you change the **study**, thus, rendering the page anew with componentWillReceiveProps, the new forms that are loaded are there, but with blank values (no initial values) and an *initialized* value of `false`. They're also not selectable in any way - the form itself is one selection dropdown and 3 checkboxes, and you can't select any of them.

Refreshing the page causes the forms to work again, even on the new study.

**What I've tried:**

- Manually initializing the forms with `this.props.dispatch(initialize(form_name))`. This causes the forms to be initialized with the correct values, but there's still no way to interact with them in any way.
- Manually updatine (this.forceUpdate) on the parent's study prop change. This changed nothing
- Setting `enableReinitialize` to `true`
- Providing a `key` to the parent page so it renders fresh every time (a hack I thought would work, but either I didn't do it right or it had no effect.)
- Destroying the old forms when in the process of switching study props

Here's the code of the Parent component and the Form component. This sidebar is in a seperate component, if you want to see that for some reason just ask. There's a lot going on in these files, mostly other extraneous UI stuff for the app, but I noted where the form is rendered in the parent with `//FORM IN QUESTION IS RENDERED HERE`.

**PARENT**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import InviteUsersDialog from './InviteUsersDialog';
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Tabs, { Tab } from 'material-ui/Tabs';

import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';
import tempAvatar from '../../Assets/temp-avatar.jpg';

import ExpansionPanel, {
  ExpansionPanelDetails,
  ExpansionPanelSummary,
} from 'material-ui/ExpansionPanel';

import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

import ExpandMoreIcon from 'material-ui-icons/ExpandMore';

import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { getUsersAction, getInvestigationPermissionsAction, resetUsersError, destroyFormsAction } from '../../actions/manage';

import { MenuItem } from 'material-ui/Menu';
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm, getFormValues, change, reset, destroy } from 'redux-form';

import {
  Checkbox,
  RadioGroup,
  Select,
  TextField,
  Switch,
} from 'redux-form-material-ui'

import PermissionsForm from './PermissionsForm';

import compose from 'recompose/compose';

class Manage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        if (this.props.investigation) {
            this.props.getUsersAction(this.props.investigation)
        }
    }

    state = {
        inviteOpen: false,
        expanded: null,
        value: 0
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.investigation !== nextProps.investigation) {
            this.props.getUsersAction(nextProps.investigation)

        }
    }

    handleInviteOpen = () => {
        this.setState({
            inviteOpen: true
        })
    }

    updateOnSave = () => {
        this.setState({
            expanded: null
        })
        this.props.getUsersAction(this.props.investigation).then(() => {
            this.props.getInvestigationPermissionsAction(this.props.investigation)
        })
    }

    closeOnCancel = () => {
        this.setState({
            expanded: null
        })
    }

    closeDialog = () => {
        this.setState({
            inviteOpen: false
        })
    }

    handleChange = (event, value) => {
        console.log(value)
        this.setState({ value });
    };

    handleChangeIndex = index => {
        this.setState({ value: index });
    };

    handleExpansionChange = panel => (event, expanded) => {
        this.setState({
          expanded: expanded ? panel : false,
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { expanded } = this.state;
        let inviteUsers = null;
        if (this.state.inviteOpen === true) {
            inviteUsers = (
                <InviteUsersDialog open={this.state.inviteOpen} updateOnSave={this.updateOnSave} closeDialog={this.closeDialog}/>
            )
        } else {
            inviteUsers = null;
        }

        if (this.props.usersError) {
            this.props.history.push('/dash')
            this.props.resetUsersError()
        }

        let usersList = null;
        if (this.props.users) {
            console.log("USERS:", this.props.users)
            usersList = (
                <div className={this.props.classes.usersExpansions}>
                    <ExpansionPanel className={this.props.classes.expansionPanel} expanded={false}>
                      <ExpansionPanelSummary className={this.props.classes.expansionSummary} expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon className={this.props.classes.headerExpandMore}/>}>
                        <div className={this.props.classes.headerAvatarContainer}>
                            <div className={this.props.classes.userInfo}>
                                <Typography className={this.props.classes.headingName}>Name</Typography>
                                <Typography className={this.props.classes.headingEmail}>Email</Typography>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Typography className={this.props.classes.headerStatus}>Status</Typography>
                        <Typography className={this.props.classes.headerPermissions}>Permissions</Typography>
                      </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                    </ExpansionPanel>
                {this.props.users.currentUsers.map((user) =>
                    <ExpansionPanel className={this.props.classes.expansionPanel} expanded={expanded === user.email + '-' + this.props.investigation} onChange={this.handleExpansionChange(user.email + '-' + this.props.investigation)}>
                      <ExpansionPanelSummary className={this.props.classes.expansionSummary} expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
                        <div className={this.props.classes.avatarContainer}>
                            <Avatar
                                alt={user.name}
                                src={user.avatarImg ? "data:image/jpeg;base64," + user.avatarImg : tempAvatar}
                                className={this.props.classes.avatar}
                                style={{ borderRadius: 2.1 }}
                            />
                            <div className={this.props.classes.userInfo}>
                                <Typography className={this.props.classes.headingName}>{user.name}</Typography>
                                <Typography className={this.props.classes.headingEmail}>{user.email}</Typography>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Typography className={this.props.classes.status}>{expanded === user.email + '-' + this.props.investigation ? '' : 'Activated'}</Typography>
                        <Typography className={this.props.classes.headingPermissions}>{expanded === user.email + '-' + this.props.investigation ? '' : user.permissionsArr.join(', ')}</Typography>
                      </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                      <ExpansionPanelDetails className={this.props.classes.detailsContainer}>
                        //FORM IN QUESTION IS RENDERED HERE
                        <PermissionsForm 
                         form={`PermissionsForm_${user.identifier + '-' + this.props.investigation}`} 
                         updateOnSave={this.updateOnSave} closeOnCancel={this.closeOnCancel} 
                         loggedInUser={user.email === localStorage.getItem('userEmail') ? true : false} 
                         formName={`PermissionsForm_${user.identifier + '-' + this.props.investigation}`} 
                         initialValues={{identifier: user.identifier, viewPermissions: user.permissions.viewEntries === true ? 'allEntries' : 'ownEntries', addEntriesPermissions: true, exportPermissions: user.permissions.export, manageInvestPermissions: user.permissions.manageInvest}}/>
                      </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                    </ExpansionPanel>
                )}
                {this.props.users.pendingUsers.map((user) =>
                    <ExpansionPanel className={this.props.classes.expansionPanel} expanded={false} onChange={this.handleExpansionChange(user.email + '-' + this.props.investigation)}>
                      <ExpansionPanelSummary className={this.props.classes.expansionSummary} expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon className={this.props.classes.headerExpandMore}/>}>
                        <div className={this.props.classes.avatarContainer}>
                            <Avatar
                                alt={user.name}
                                src={tempAvatar}
                                className={this.props.classes.avatar}
                                style={{ borderRadius: 0 }}
                            />
                            <div className={this.props.classes.userInfo}>
                                <Typography className={this.props.classes.headingEmail}>{user.email}</Typography>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Typography className={this.props.classes.status}>Pending</Typography>
                        <Typography className={this.props.classes.headingPermissions}>{user.permissionsArr.join(', ')}</Typography>
                      </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                    </ExpansionPanel>
                )}
                </div>
            )
        }
        return (
            <div className={this.props.classes.container}>
                <div className={this.props.classes.pageHeaderContainer}>
                    <h2 className={this.props.classes.title}>Manage users</h2>
                    <Button color="primary" raised className={this.props.classes.inviteButton} onClick={this.handleInviteOpen}>Invite user</Button>
                </div>
                {inviteUsers}
                <AppBar position="static" color="default" className={this.props.classes.tabsAppBar}>
                  <Tabs
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    indicatorColor="primary"
                    textColor="primary"
                    fullWidth
                    className={this.props.classes.tabs}
                  >
                    <Tab label="People" />
                    <Tab label="Groups" />
                  </Tabs>
                </AppBar>
                <SwipeableViews
                  axis={'x'}
                  index={this.state.value}
                  onChangeIndex={this.handleChangeIndex}
                >
                <div className={this.props.classes.peopleContainer}>
                    {usersList}
                </div>
                <div>

                </div>
                </SwipeableViews>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


const styles = {
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return { 
    investigation: state.manage.savedInvest,
    users: state.manage.authorizedUsers,
    usersError: state.manage.usersError
  };
}


export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, {getUsersAction, getInvestigationPermissionsAction, resetUsersError, destroyFormsAction}),
  withStyles(styles)
)(Manage);
```

**FORM**

```
import React from 'react';
import Dialog, {
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle,
} from 'material-ui/Dialog';

import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import Input, { InputLabel } from 'material-ui/Input';

import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

import List, { ListItem, ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from 'material-ui/List';

import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider'

import SelectBase from 'material-ui/Select';
import { MenuItem } from 'material-ui/Menu';
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm, getFormValues, change, reset, initialize } from 'redux-form';
import { patchPermissionsAction } from '../../actions/manage';
import { resetFormsAction } from '../../actions/dashboard';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Tooltip from 'material-ui/Tooltip';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import compose from 'recompose/compose';

import {
  Checkbox,
  RadioGroup,
  Select,
  TextField,
  Switch,
} from 'redux-form-material-ui'

const required = value => (value == null ? 'Required' : undefined)

class PermissionsForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    form: PropTypes.string
  }
  submit = (values) => {
    this.props.patchPermissionsAction(values, this.props.investigation).then(() => {
      this.props.updateOnSave();
    })
  }

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.props.closeOnCancel();
    this.props.dispatch(reset(this.props.formName))
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("!")
    if(!this.props.initialized) {
      console.log("!!")
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props

    let managePerm = null;
    if (this.props.loggedInUser) {
      managePerm = (
        <Tooltip id="tooltip-top-start" title="Coming soon" placement="top">
          <Typography className={this.props.classes.status}>Manage users</Typography>
        </Tooltip>
      )
    } else {
      managePerm = (<Typography className={this.props.classes.status}>Manage users</Typography>)
    }

    return (
      <div className={this.props.classes.permFormContainer}>
        <Divider />
        <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this.submit) }>
        <div className={this.props.classes.innerFormContainer}>
            <div className={this.props.classes.groupsContainer}>
            <br/>
            </div>
            <div className={this.props.classes.fieldContainer}>
              <Typography className={this.props.classes.status}>View</Typography>
              <Field name="viewPermissions" component={Select}>
                <MenuItem value="ownEntries">View own entries</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="allEntries">View all entries</MenuItem>
              </Field>
            </div>
            <div className={this.props.classes.fieldContainer}>
            <Tooltip id="tooltip-top-start" title="Coming soon" placement="top">
              <Typography className={this.props.classes.status}>Add entries</Typography>
            </Tooltip>
            <Field
              name="addEntriesPermissions"
              component={Checkbox}
              normalize={v => !!v}
              disabled={true}
            />
            </div>
            <div className={this.props.classes.fieldContainer}> 
            <Typography className={this.props.classes.status}>Export data</Typography>
            <Field
              name="exportPermissions"
              component={Checkbox}
              normalize={v => !!v}
            />
            </div>
            <div className={this.props.classes.fieldContainer}>
            {managePerm}
            <Field
              name="manageInvestPermissions"
              component={Checkbox}
              normalize={v => !!v}
              disabled={this.props.loggedInUser === true ? true : false}
            />
            </div>
          </div>
        <Divider />
        <div className={this.props.classes.actionButtons}>

          <Tooltip id="tooltip-top-start" title="Coming soon" placement="top">
          <Button color="error" className={this.props.classes.deleteButton}>
            Delete account
          </Button>
          </Tooltip>
          <div className={this.props.classes.saveAndCancelButtons}>
            <Button onClick={this.handleCancel} className={this.props.classes.cancelButton}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button type="submit" disabled={submitting} color="primary" className={this.props.classes.saveButton}>
              Save
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return { 
    investigation: state.manage.savedInvest,
    investTitle: state.manage.savedInvestTitle
  };
}

const styles = theme => ({
});

const reduxFormmPermissions = reduxForm({
  enableReinitialize : true
})(PermissionsForm);

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, {patchPermissionsAction}),
  withStyles(styles)
)(reduxFormmPermissions);
```

Thanks much for anybody who can help me get to the bottom of this. Real head-banger.

Comment: you are importing PermissionsForm but you are exporting reduxFormmPermissions, Also you defined reduxFormmPermissions as a const try changing it to let. both are my hunches but cant pinpoint without debugging :(

Comment: Hmm, my guess is that the import is fine, because I'm importing the file (which is called PermissionsForm) and the default export of that file is reduxFormmPermissions (didn't notice the typo there, but at least I was consistent :) ). Tried changing the const to let, didn't seem to do much. If you have any other suggestions, let me know! Thank you!

Comment: When changed to study form console log this.state and i guess the state might not be updated with the new values.  if this is the case you will not rerender the UI to see any new data, and on refresh its reflecting

Comment: one thing you can do is add this.setstate inside componentwillrecieveprops which will rerender UI without refreshing

Comment: I'll give that a try as soon as possible, and let you know how it worked.

Comment: ddin't yield any results, sorry for the lack of response, just getting back to this problem

Answer (score 0):

The way you're building the form seems odd you should be able to do it with one compose like so. Just a hunch but The reduxForm HOC might be blocking the form from re-rendering because its state isn't changing when you refresh. The connect HOC should go before it to prevent this.

```
compose(
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps, {patchPermissionsAction}),
    reduxForm({ enableReinitialize: true }),
    withStyles(styles)
)(PermissionsForm);
```

Comment: This seems brilliant. I'm not 100% sure its correct, as I've never seen it written like this (in the few examples I've seen) but it really does seem like its correct. I will try this today, and let you know. Thanks a bunch man, will get back to you!

Comment: Yeah, just a hunch hopefully it fixes your issue. I'd start implementing presentational and container components so this doesn't happen again. It should also make your code easier to test and split things up nicely. You have a container component that's responsible for pulling state from your store and dispatching actions. You then have a presentational form component that is wrapped with Your withStyles and reduxForm HOC.

The god Dan Abramov has a good post on the pattern https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: Having a good understanding of how HOCs work and building some of your own is also super helpful for debugging this stuff.
 
https://medium.com/dailyjs/react-composing-higher-order-components-hocs-3a5288e78f55